# Force permissions non domain Mac server share

Tags: samba, mac-osx-server, file-permissions

I have a Mac server which is accessed by both Macs and PCs. I need every file in this specific samba share to have 777 permissions regardless of the write permissions given by the client. The computers cannot join a domain because of the working situation but the connection to the server is authenticated.

My current solution is setting the umasks on the Macs and the PCs (because most of them are virtuals on the macs) will inherit the permissions from the Mac. But the solution is not working. We have interns that follow the byod rule. And their computers don't write properly to the server.

My question is how do I force all writes on the server to 777?

I'm at my wits end and am looking to set up a duct tape solution of having a cron job reset the permissions every 10 minutes. I would rather not do this so if you have a proper solution it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: umask doesn't set permissions; it just masks some suggested permissions out.  I don't think there is a way to do this, but good luck.

Comment: Thanks. The umask seems to save all files as 777 for some reason. Its bought me a bit of time.